# How do I calculate the next day (e.g., Monday) after X days out (e.g., 5) for any given date (including in the future)?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

Have been drumming my head about this...

My current method, below, only works for past dates. If the start_date is like 2 months from now... it doesn't work.

```
def date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(day=ENV['day_to_start_plans'], number_of_days=ENV['min_days_out'], start_date)
    # Explanation uses Monday as an example
    # When was the last Monday?
    date = Date.parse(day) 

    # Was the last Monday after the start_date? If so, then there's no difference between the last Monday and the next Monday; else, the next Monday is 7 days from the last Monday
    delta = date > (start_date) ? 0 : 7 
    actual_next_day = date + delta

    # Is there a minimum of Y number_of_days between the next Monday and the start_date? If not, bump to the following Monday by adding 7 more days
    delta_2 = (actual_next_day - start_date) < number_of_days ? 7 : 0
    actual_next_day + delta_2 #returned value
end
```

I need to update this so that for ANY start_date, whether it's today, five weeks ago, or five months after today, I can find the next (day of the week) that is at least (a certain number of days out) days out.

For example

```
date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start("Monday", 5, Date.parse(May 23,2015))
# ==> June 1, 2015

date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start("Wednesday", 7, Date.parse(May 8,2015))
# ==> May 20, 2015

date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start("Friday", 3, Date.parse(June 15,2015))
# ==> June 19, 2015
```

FYI I do have rails, so feel free to shout out with the `advance` or `change` helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the week days as numbers (0 for sunday ... 6 for saturday), you could use the following formula to determine the desired date:

```
def date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(wday, number_of_days, start_date)
  day_ahead = start_date + number_of_days.days
  (day_ahead) + ((7 - day_ahead.wday + wday) % 7).days
end
```

Some tests:

```
dates = [
  { wday: 1, n_days: 5, start_date: Date.parse('May 23,2015') },
  { wday: 3, n_days: 7, start_date: Date.parse('May 8,2015') },
  { wday: 5, n_days: 3, start_date: Date.parse('June 15,2015') },
  { wday: 3, n_days: 1, start_date: Date.parse('May 13,2015') },
  { wday: 5, n_days: 1, start_date: Date.parse('May 20,2015') }
]

dates.each do |date|
  puts date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(date[:wday], date[:n_days], date[:start_date])
end

# => 2015-06-01
# => 2015-05-20
# => 2015-06-19
# => 2015-05-20
# => 2015-05-22
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain Ruby, this is how I would do it

```
def date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(target_wday, skip, d)
  d += skip  # add "skip" number of days 

  # now keep add a day while checking wday (weekday) until we hit our target
  # 0 = Monday, ..., 6 = Sunday

  (0..6).each do |i|
    break if d.wday == target_wday
    d += 1
  end

  puts "Next Tuesday is #{d}"
```

Example usage:

```
# Find the next Tuesday (1) 5 days after June 15, 2015
date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(1, 5, Date.parse("June 15,2015"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
def date_of_next_X_day_Y_days_out_from_Z_start(day=ENV['day_to_start_plans'], number_of_days=ENV['min_days_out'], start_date)
  real_start_date = start_date + number_of_days     
  until real_start_date.wday == Date.parse(day).wday
    real_start_date += 1
  end  
  real_start_date
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def next_date(target_wday, skip_num_days, start_date)

  date = Date.parse(target_wday)
  delta = date > start_date ? 0 : 7
  actual_next_day = date + delta 

  # define delta_2 so you're able to use += 
  delta_2 = 0

  # calculates how many weeks ahead the start date is
  repeat = (actual_next_day - start_date).to_i % 7

  # removes the current week you're calculating
  ( repeat - 1 ).times do 
    delta_2 += (actual_next_day - start_date) < skip_num_days ? 7 : 0
  end

  actual_next_day + delta_2
end
```

Working off of your current method, the issue is you're not taking into account how many weeks ahead you're `start_date` is of `date`, so you're return date is falling short. 
You can calculate how many weeks ahead the `start_date` is and repeat your calculation for `delta_2` while continually adding the value of the conditional to it. `delta_2` will now include 1) how many weeks ahead your `start_date` is and 2) add on an additional week if `actual_next_day` falls short of the amount of days to skip.